# Core Plot: x-Axis should remain visible while scrolling horizontally (or vice versa)

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-plot

I am using core plot to make a line graph with a long xAxis-range. I made the vertical direction of the graph fixed/constant and let it only scroll horizontally. However, if I start scrolling/swiping horizontally, the y-Axis will not move along (like the x-label). The y-Axis is only visible at starting point of the graph. I would appreciate if somebody can help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How to achieve this,make y axis constant and allow scrolling only x - axis.I am new to core plot can you pls elaborate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `axisConstraints`:

```
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```